# What does RAW stand for in the postproduction world?

Tags: post-processing, raw

So, I know the meaning of RAW file in the post production world. But, does anyone know exactly what does RAW stand for? I believe it has something related with Read And Write but I haven't found anything concrete, Any ideas?